# How can I use typeahead to fetch/present objects but take in and respond with strings?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-reactive-forms

The ng-bootstrap typeahead element allows fetching an array of object suggestions and then selecting one so that the model becomes the selected object.

[The full code can be seen in this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LVso2QKJVjrN67x3igg?p=preview). Test it by searching for a US state then observing the `model` output.

Here is the template:

```
<label for="typeahead-template">Search for a state:</label>
<input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model" [ngbTypeahead]="search" [resultTemplate]="rt"
  [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
<hr>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
```

When you search for "Alabama" the model does not become Alabama, but rather

```
{
  "name": "Alabama",
  "flag": "5/5c/Flag_of_Alabama.svg/45px-Flag_of_Alabama.svg.png"
}
```

In my situation, I would like to get the model as `Alabama`. I don't want to send the image and other data back to the server in my form.

I've tried using the `(selectItem)` event provided by ng-bootstrap, and manually changing value in it but this does not work. The model remains the same - an object and not a string!.

i.e.

```
 selectItem(e: NgbTypeaheadSelectItemEvent, fubi: any ){
    console.log("e.item.name", e.item.name);
    this.addressForm.patchValue({
      statename: e.item.name
    });
  }
```

**My form's `statename` property is not updating when called this way**

Any ideas why not ? I've tried all the obvious ones, I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track with the selectItem event. Maybe you just didn't quite get the syntax right?

In the input definition, you probably want to:

1. remove the ngModel reference
2. replace it with a reference to the function you want to run when the selectItem event is fired (this function can set "model" appropriately...or "statename" perhaps...whatever floats your boat)

like so:

```
<input id="typeahead-template" 
       type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       (selectItem)="setModel($event)" 
       [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
       [resultTemplate]="rt"
       [inputFormatter]="formatter" />
```

and then, in your typeahead-template.ts file, add the function:

```
setModel(e: NgbTypeaheadSelectItemEvent, fubi: any) {
  this.model = e.item.name;
}
```

I [forked your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6uGW4geCcvSDqyj1Eou4?p=preview) with these mods, and it sets the "model" value to "Alabama" as desired...you can probably take it from there to do whatever you need to do. Hope that helps!

Comment: Could you maybe modify your Plunkr so that it demonstrates what you are trying to do with your FormGroup and FormControl? I can't tell what you're trying to do...from the first look, I figured you had created a function - calling it selectItem - rather than naming the function whatever you want and referring to it in the (selectItem) attribute on your input tag.

Comment: Never mind my last comment. I got it working. Problem was I had accidentally removed `inputFormatter`

Comment: Great! Glad to know it.