# ngbTypeahead use only id field for ngModel instead of whole object

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

How can I tell `ngbTypeahead` to put only the `id` of the selected object in the `ngModel` and retrieve the current value from the `id` of the current `ngModel`.

e.g I have Countries in the form of `{id: 1, name: USA}` I want to display "USA" but only want 1 in my `ngModel`.

I use result and `inputFormatter` for displaying "USA" but I always get the whole object in my `ngModel` instead of the `id`.

Comment: I think that's a bad idea, but here's an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n8uuuc?file=app%2Ftypeahead-template.ts. Of course, the stateByName() should really be changed to be O(1) rather than O(n) to make that more efficient.

Comment: I see can you explain why you consider it a bad idea? I wanted to keep the form model simple

Comment: Because it's more logical to store the object and access it directly than to be forced to get the object by ID every time you need it.

Comment: Here's the right way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643662/how-can-i-use-typeahead-to-fetch-present-objects-but-take-in-and-respond-with-st

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use typeahead to fetch/present objects but take in and respond with strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643662/how-can-i-use-typeahead-to-fetch-present-objects-but-take-in-and-respond-with-st)